# more than one data from controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to show more that on data from controller to the same item.if am trying to set another condition in ng-repeat="file in fileno & filedet in descript & status in statusno" the item is not displaying

**controller**

```
.controller('caseFileCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.fileno = ["1", "2", "3"];
    $scope.descript = ["consumer", "litrel", "accident"];
    $scope.statusno = ["open", "closed", "closed"];
})
```

**view**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item item-icon-right href="#/filedetails" ng-repeat="file in fileno">File Ref No:{{file}}
        <br> Description:{{filedetail}}
        <br> Status:{{status}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer items by corresponding index:

```
<ion-item item-icon-right href="#/filedetails" ng-repeat= "file in fileno">
    File Ref No: {{file}}<br>
    Description: {{desript[$index]}}<br>
    Status: {{statusno[$index]}}
</ion-item>
```

But ideally you modify your data structure to use array of objects instead of three separate arrays:

```
.controller('caseFileCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.files = [
        {number: "1", description: "consumer", status: "open"},
        {number: "2", description: "literl", status: "closed"},
        {number: "3", description: "accident", status: "closed"}
    ];
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<ion-item item-icon-right href="#/filedetails" ng-repeat= "file in files">
    File Ref No: {{file.number}}<br>
    Description: {{file.desription}}<br>
    Status: {{file.status}}
</ion-item>
```